# unable to install framework-res.apk on Windows 10

Tags: reverse-engineering, apktool

when trying to run 'apktool if framework-res.apk' i get this error

```
C:\Windows>apktool if framework-res.apk
S: WARNING: Could not write to (C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\apktool\framework), using C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Temp\ instead...
S: Please be aware this is a volatile directory and frameworks could go missing, please utilize --frame-path if the default storage directory is unavailable
I: Framework installed to: C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Temp\1.apk
```

Apktool.jar and apktool.bat are both in my windows c directory  I am able to decompile apks using 'apktool d `<file.apk>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do quite a few steps to resolve this.

I recommend using the `--frame-path [folder]` parameter and describing the folder you want the framework resources to reside.

Comment: Could please tell elaborately i didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as administrator and set the directory of apktool with the command "cd "... I solved